# Java - file.length() returns 0

Tags: java

For some reason, even after doing a file.exists() check, the value comes off as 0, even thou im sure that these directories aren't empty, since I've checked c:\ included.

```
 File folder = new File(directama);
    File[] listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();

    for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {

    if(listOfFile.exists()){    

        String str = tamanhovari.getText();          //IRRELEVANT
        Long valisizeGB = parseLong(str);            //IRRELEVANT   
        String length = valueOf(listOfFile.length());//IRRELEVANT
        Long bytevalue = parseLong(length);          //IRRELEVANT    
        String gbdivisor ="10737418284";             //IRRELEVANT
        Long bytetogb = parseLong(gbdivisor);       //IRRELEVANT
        Long valisizeBT=valisizeGB*bytetogb;        //IRRELEVANT
        Long actualfilesize = bytevalue/bytetogb;   //IRRELEVANT

        if (listOfFile.length()<= valisizeBT) {
            if(listOfFile.isFile()){
            }
            else if (listOfFile.isDirectory()) {
                model.addRow(new Object[]{listOfFile.getName(),actualfilesize + " GB" });
            }
            else{}

    }}
    else{}
    }
```

it SHOULD logically return the value of the folder in GB's, but even when I remove the GB formating, and try returning only the byte value, it still only returns 0.

Any suggestions? I've pretty much done almost everything.

EDIT: SOLVED! Thanks for the quick responses! To retrieve the size of a folder, one must use file.sizeOfDirectory() and not file.length()

Comment: The file length of a folder is always 0.

Comment: have you tried listOfFile.isFile() to see what it returns? If true, then you definitely have file(s).

Comment: Why are you using `else{}`? If it's irrelevant, add `//IRRELEVANT` as you did with your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29):

```
The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc of "length" method:

> Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname. The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the actual lenght of a file not a directory.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) :

> The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.
>
> Return the length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes.